# What instrument should I use to vary the power given to a heating element?

Tags: electricity, experimental-physics

I have a nickel-chrome wire as a heating element and I want to vary the power given to it to control the amount of heating the wire produces. Which instrument should I use? Please don't give theoretical explanations here, tell me how I can do it practically.

Comment: The answer from @Olin assumes you want very tight control.  But perhaps you are just heating water or making a toaster.  To get an answer that you can use, you'll have to tell us more about your goals.

Comment: This is the PHYSICS site.  Nothing practical here.  You want practical, you need the ENGINEERING site.

Comment: @OlinLathrop is that sarcasm? I really hope you're not actually trying to scare off would-be experimentalists from this site.

Comment: We really need to know the target temperate tolerance. It would also be nice to know the length and resistance of the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simpler times, [a rheostat](http://www.resistorguide.com/rheostat/) would do the job. It diminishes and increases the current according to need:

> A rheostat is a variable resistor which is used to control current. They are able to vary the resistance in a circuit without interruption. The construction is very similar to the construction of a potentiometers

Microelectronics is much more efficient and so the use has fallen off

> Rheostats were often used as power control devices, for example to control light intensity (dimmer), speed of motors, heaters and ovens. Nowadays they are not used for this function anymore. This is because of their relatively low efficiency. In power control applications they are replaced by switching electronics

Answer (score 1):

Power is voltage times current, either of which is relatively easy to control.  If your accuracy requirement is not so tight that the change in resistance of the heating element matters, you can simply assume power is either proportional to the square of the voltage or the square of the current.

For tighter control, you need to do the math.  Generally you'd have a microcontroller controlling a power supply.  The micro measures both the voltage and current, multiplies them, then controls the power supply up or down to regulate the voltage x current product to the desired value.

It's no stretch at all for a micro to do a loop iteration every 10 µs (100 kHz rate), for example.  That will be much faster than the thermal time constants, so the micro is effectively controlling power in "real time", apparently continuously from the outside point of view.

In summary, this is a fairly basic control problem, with the speed requirements well within the range of what many microcontrollers can handle.  Attack it accordingly.

Comment: "For tighter control, you need to do the math." That or sense the temperature and feed back. That's not very practical for a hot wire foam cutter, but is standard for electric heaters. Of course, the precision required and the physical parameters of the system need to be established first, which the question completely fails to do.

Comment: @What: The OP specified power control, not temperature control, so temperature feedback wouldn't actually solve the problem.  Agreed though that the question is thin on specifics.  Maybe he does want temperature control, but for now I'm answering what was asked.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop:  I need to measure the heat power(I^2*R) produced by the wire when I give certain power input(by varying I or V). R is a function of temperature. For a given material I can find this relation easily and if I can measure the temperature(using non-contact thermometer), I can calculate R. My question is how do I measure current(I) that is passed through the wire and how to I control the current that is passed(hence control the power output by the wire)?

Comment: @Sara: There are various ways, but those are electrical engineering questions.  This is the physics site.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple options available. The most simple one is a potentiometer that changes it's resistance when you turn it around.

Comment: Perhaps impractical (and certainly inefficient) depending on the application.  The OP has to give us more information.

Comment: @Ignacio: I need to measure the heat power(I^2*R) produced by the wire when I give certain power input(by varying I or V). R is a function of temperature. For a given material I can find this relation easily and if I can measure the temperature(using non-contact thermometer), I can calculate R. My question is how do I measure current(I) that is passed through the wire and how to I control the current that is passed(hence control the power output by the wire)?